Terraform: Trigger a resource in another file
I have two files

cloud/modules/gcp-gke/main.tf
cloud/modules/gcp-helm/main.tf

I have multiple resources defined in cloud/modules/gcp-gke/main.tf and one of them is google_container_node_pool. I have no custom modules. whenever this is run I need kubernetes_config_map resource in gcp/modules/gcp-helm/main.tf to be executed.
Resource kubernetes_config_map  in cloud/modules/gcp-helm/main.tf can be executed independently. But whenever
resource google_container_node_pool in cloud/modules/gcp-gke/main.tf gets executed then
resource  kubernetes_config_map  in cloud/modules/gcp-helm/main.tf should be executed
Any suggestion on how to achieve this
cloud/modules/gcp-gke/main.tf
resource "google_container_node_pool" "ownnodepool" {
  for_each          = var.node_pools
  name              = var.name
  project           = var.gcp_project
  location          = var.gcp_region
   ...
}

cloud/modules/gcp-helm/main.tf
resource "kubernetes_config_map" "nodespec" {
  depends_on = [kubernetes_namespace.o9_namespaces]
  count      = length(var.node_pool_cm_namespace_suffixes)
  metadata {
    name      = "node-pool-specs"
    ...
  }
  data = {
  ...
  }
}



Please add module declarations to the question content.

@MatthewSchuchard I don't have any module declarations. I only have resources declared in both the files.

Are you saying they are both root modules?

yes, both are root modules

So you are applying code for one module at a time? You are not calling both from different root module?

@Marko yes. applying code for one module at a time
